# How to set the radio buttons for the attendance record PHP CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, styles, structure

I want to create an attendance record form where teacher can record attendance of the students and send it to database to store. Here I am using radio buttons and I want these buttons to only select either present or absent or authorise however right now it is not implementing what I want to do.  Right now the selection of the radio buttons is not working properly so can you please me to put the radio buttons in specific way so that it selects only present or absent or authorise. I think we have to use CSS or javaScript for this HTML form syntax but the question is how. Thank you in advance.

```
echo '<table action="process.php" method="POST" class="tableEchoPupilAttendance" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Present</th>
        <th>Absent</th>
        <th>Authorise</th>
    </tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>
        <td><img width='70' height='60' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['image'])."'/></td>
        <td>" .$row['name']. $row['surname']."</td>
        <td> <input type='radio' name='present' value=''/>  </td>
        <td> <input type='radio' name='absent' value=''/>  </td>
        <td> <input type='radio' name='late' value=''/>  </td>
    </tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are grouped by the `name` attribute. To have just one of the three radio buttons on each row selectable, their `name`s must be the same, and their desired values stored in the `value` attribute.

I think it's fair to assume you have an `id` of some sort on your result rows. Therefore the following code might work:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <td><input type="radio" name="att[<?=$row['id'];?>]" value="present" /><td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="att[<?=$row['id'];?>]" value="absent" /><td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="att[<?=$row['id'];?>]" value="late" /><td>
    <?
}
```

Submitting this will give you an array with content such as this:

```
[1] => 'present',
[3] => 'absent',
[4] => 'present',
[6] => 'late'
```

Using numeric values is usually a good idea, however the code won't be as readable.

Answer (score -1):

Radio buttons are grouped only if they have the same name. So what you want to do is:

```
<td> <input type='radio' name='attendance[<?php print $row['id']; ?>]' value='present'/>  </td>
<td> <input type='radio' name='attendance[<?php print $row['id']; ?>]' value='absent'/>  </td>
<td> <input type='radio' name='attendance[<?php print $row['id']; ?>]' value='late'/>  </td>
```

Comment: This will only work when there is just one row of data.